# Adding data to a dataframe based on groups

Tags: r, dplyr, file-import, gff

I'm working with bioinformatic data, with a gene in each row and statistics/metadata in the columns. Some genes are from the same organism which is indicated by column "ID", and I grouped the data on this variable.

```
data <- data %>%
  group_by(ID)
```

I want to add data from another file based on the ID (the grouping factor), so that rows with ID = a should have data from a file named a.gff and so on. The data I would like to add is from a .gff file containing gene locations. There is a gff file for ID=a, one for ID=b, one for ID=c etc named according to the ID (e.g. "a.gff").

What the data looks like:

| Gene | ID |
| --- | --- |
| CelA | a |
| CelB | a |
| Atl | b |
| prT | a |
| HUl | c |

Is there a way to implement a function to open a file for each ID grouping, do an operation and move onto the next ID?

I'm quite new to R, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is by reading first all the *.gff* files. I'm not familiar with the format so my example will use the *.csv* extension. The following code reads all the files in the "dir" directory as a list column, then unnests it so is a regular tibble.

After that you can just `left_join()` using both tibbles and then group by `ID`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

binded <- tibble(
    file = list.files("dir"), # can remove before the join
    location = list.files("dir", full.names = TRUE), # can remove before the join
    ID = str_remove(file, "\.csv"),
    df = map(location, read_csv)
) %>% 
    unnest(df)

data %>% 
    left_join(binded)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the problem is that the files total 1GB.

Comment: Then, you can previously create a function to work with the data and replace de call to `read_csv()` inside the `map()` for a call to your function.